# htaccess - RewriteRule without redirect not working

Tags: htaccess

I had to create 3 page templates to display some content retrieved from different webservices outside of Wordpress.

The templates are:

```
page-collections.php
page-collection.php
page-productDetail.php
```

I've also created 3 new pages and associated the templates.

```
collections --> page-collections.php
collection --> page-collection.php
product detail --> page-productDetail.php
```

Since the content comes from external webservices I don't have an url to access a specific collection / product. So in order to achieve 'pretty' urls I'm trying to rewrite an url from:

```
https://www.website.com/collections/exampleName
```

Where `exampleName` is the name of a collection which I use to retrieve the content from the ws.

to:

```
https://www.website.com/collections/collection/?collectionName=exampleName
```

I've placed the following rule before the `# BEGIN WordPress` directive:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(collections)/(.+)$ /collections/collection/?collectionName=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

But instead of the expected page I get a 404 error.

If I replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]` the rewrite works but it forces a 301 redirect which is not what I want. I just need the rewrite to happen.

Do you have any hint on why this happens?

Comment: What's the reason for doing this? Normally people are trying to do the opposite, what is `name`? Note that `name` is a reserved keyword as it's used in WP_Query and rewrite rules as a query argument. If you are trying to use it for logic in a page template then that will never work, and you can't use it. `name` is used by WordPress to request posts with a specific slug

Comment: @TomJNowell I have a structure like Collections --> product list --> product detail, I've created a page template for all the 3 pages, but the data is retrieved from an external webservice. Since the data are not articles/custom post types I don't have an actual url, that's why I wanted to use the url `/test/test-detail/value` but rewrite it as `/test/test-detail?collection=value` so I just need to change the `value` part to access a different product list (`test-detail` is one of the 3 template pages). The `name` parameter is actually called `collection`, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: If it's actually `collection` can you change your examples? By trying to make it generic you've hidden your problem and introduced an unrelated bug, until you fix this your question is either extremely confusing, or you'll get answers trying to fix `?name=` which are useless to you ( you can't rely on people reading comments either )

Comment: @TomJNowell yes sorry, will edit with more informations and updated example

Comment: Also, is this a mapping? or a _redirect_? What was the reason for using HTAccess instead of WP rewrite rules? The distinction is important, there are no rewrites in your question, it's unclear if you want the user to see `/test/test-detail?collection=abc` or if you want users to see `/test/test-detail/abc`, and fi that's the case, why not ask how to achieve that? The solution to that problem is much easier and has nothing to do with HTAccess, but would also require changes to the code that looks up the `collection` parameter ( how is `collection` being processed? )

Comment: @TomJNowell I've added a bit of context and updated the examples, let me know if something is still unclear. Regarding the last questions, I wanted this to be just a rewrite, so if a user access `/test/test-detail/abc` he keeps the same url but the actual loaded page becomes `/test/test-detail?collection=abc`. Also sorry if i'm using some wrong terminology but i'm a newbie when it comes to htaccess

Comment: Thanks those edits are super useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a rewrite rule to map to one of those pages with something like this:

```php
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'myparamname/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?myparamname=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );
```

The first parameter of `add_rewrite_rule` is a regular expression to match a URL. The second parameter is an `index.php` non-pretty permalink URL, the URL parameters map directly into `WP_Query` arguments.

So if we take your first page as an example `collections/collection/example`:

```php
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'collections/collection/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?name=collection&collection_parameter=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} );
```

`name=collection` tells WordPress we want the page with the slug `collection`, and `collection_parameter` is how we're passing the final parts value.

We then need to allow the use of `collection_parameter`, and adjust the page template to use it instead of `$_GET`

To grab the value from your page template:

```php
$collection = get_query_var( 'collection_parameter' );
```

To whitelist the parameter we need to add it to the whitelist:

```php
/**
 * Register custom query vars
 *
 * @param array $vars The array of available query variables
 * 
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars
 */
function myplugin_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'collection_parameter';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_register_query_vars' );
```

Don't forget to flush rewrite rules, and you can extend this for the other two pages.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to be of help, you might be interested in looking up virtual pages, which build on this to eliminate the need for a page and a page template, do a search on the site and you'll find a few questions about this that should be informative

Comment: I'll for sure look that up in the coming days, might come in handy. Again, thank you for all the informations, really helpful!